# Metodo Image.FromFile() usando una variable, en C#, Windows forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, spire

Estoy desarrollando un sistema en windows forms, en donde quiero que la imagen seleccionada me la muestre en un documento word (.docx) para ello estoy utilizando una libreria llamada Spire.doc, en mi siguiente código almaceno en un buffer la imagen seleccionada en mi picture box (pxImagen es el nombre de mi Picture box):

```html
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
this.pxImagen.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
byte[] imagen = ms.GetBuffer();
```

vemos que mi variable "imagen" es de tipo byte[]

solo que en el metodo Image.FromFile() tiene permitido usar como parametro un string.
lo que intento hacer es convertir mi variable "imagen" de byte[] a un string de la siguiente forma:

```html
string imagenString = BitConverter.ToString(imagen);
Image image = Image.FromFile(imagenString);
```

solo que haciéndolo de esa manera me arroja un error el cual es "ex.Message = "La ruta de acceso especificada o el nombre de archivo (o ambos) son demasiado largos. El nombre de archivo completo debe ser inferior a 260 caracteres y el nombre del directorio debe ser inferior a 248."

la forma en la que me muestra la imagen en mi documento es

```html
Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\kroz\Pictures\miImagen.png");
```

solo que quiero saber es como usar el metodo Image.FromFile() pasandole una variable de tipo cadena

tambien he utilizado la siguiente manera

```html
Image.FromFile(imagen.ToString());
```

solo que no tengo exito alguno
lo que quisiera saber la manera correcta de utilizar ese método utilizando un parámetro o algún otro método que me haga la misma tarea, espero haberme explicado.

Comment: si ya tienes la imagen a nivel byte[] cambia el .FromFile() por .FromStream() y pasale como parametro el MemoryStream que a su vez llevara el array de byte de la imagen y listo

Comment: @Manny Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!! me ha servido muchísimo!!

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo en detalles que es lo que quieres hacer.
Pero si se que el uso que pretendes darle al método "iImage.FromFile" es erróneo y por ese camino no vas a lograr resultados, la sintaxis del método "iImage.FromFile" es la siguiente

```
public static Image FromFile (string filename)
```

El método  iImage.FromFile devuelve un objeto Image similar al que devuelve la propiedad "pxImagen.Image" de tu picture box, solo que "iImage.FromFile" lo devuelve leyéndolo desde un archivo almacenado en disco y el argumento "filename", de tipo `string` no es más que la ruta o path, donde está ubicado el archivo dentro del sistema de archivos de tu dispositivo de almacenamiento.
Hasta donde se, pues no soy experto, no existe una forma de convertir una imagen en una cadena de texto y si la hay no se para que te serviría en tu ejemplo, pues el objeto imagen ya lo tienes en la propiedad "this.pxImagen.Image" de tu picture box, si lo que quieres es insertarla en un documento de word (.docx), no creo que pienses que si conviertes tu imagen en una cadena de texto y luego le pasas esa cadena a un documento de word,como que es un procesador de texto, el word sea capaz de con esa cadena mostrarte una imagen, una imagen en word es un objeto insertado, si quieres logarlo, tendrás que utilizar la biblioteca Spire.Doc, que te permite crear y editar archivos de word desde tu codigo, desde esa biblioteca tienes que buscar el método que permite insertar imágenes que no se cual es, pero puedo asegurarte que existe y pasarle los parámetros que pide, uno de ellos debe ser tu objeto Image, eso se puede aprender haciéndolo, estudiando las ayudas disponibles y en un proceso de prueba y error.